# Is there a way to know if the user just sent an SMS?

Tags: android

Is there a way to know if the user just sent an SMS ? I mean like an intent, caught by a BroadcastReceiver when the user tap "send" in the native SMS application.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Just put this on your BroadcastReceiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.broadcast.SmsBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```